# Liferay Portlet id is already in use problem

Tags: liferay, portlet

I am currently using liferay 7.2 and performing a IPC using event and i got an error message like portlet id is already in use while deploying.also after deploy the portlet is not show in Liferay portal under sample.

What are the issues for this and How can i solve this error?

Comment: I also check liferay Forum answers.But this issue is not solved.

Comment: The error? The log?

Comment: 2019-12-10 05:49:31.278 ERROR [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: c7de4ff9-b61f-
4742-96ab-705dbfc607ce][PortletTracker:158] Portlet id ipc_sender_IpcSenderPortl
et is already in use

Comment: you don't happen to deploy a portlet with the same id from another plugin?

Comment: I am not deploying same id of a portlet with different plugin.

Comment: share the code, and maybe..

Answer (score 2):

You could get that error if you change bundle symbolic name in bnd.bnd file and don't delete old jar version from server

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @ Ana Maria
that is the issue but when I tried to delete the custom portlet then I am unable to locate that portlet in osgi/modules.

I found in   liferay_bundle_root_folder/work

folder and then I deleted and I also deleted from control panel/Apps Manager and then deployed again then my issue resolved.